# Pass parameters to Python Flask via UWSGI / NGINX

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, geoip

I am trying to use the GeoIP module with my Nginx and Uwsgi stack. All the tutorials relate to using it with fastcgi, but since I dont use fastcgi it doesnt help.

I need to get nginx to pass GeoIP data into your CGI app via custom HTTP headers, e.g.:

```
proxy_set_header X-GeoIP-Country $geoip_country_name;
proxy_set_header X-GeoIP-City    $geoip_city;
```

How do I do this with Uwsgi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

uwsgi_param key value;

Ex.

uwsgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY $geoip_country_name;

Comment: Wow I got a reply from the creator himself! Thank you ill do some reading

Comment: For clarification, is it correct that I would put this in my nginx config under location as per this link: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/uWSGIVars